# PM2 watchers not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

PM2 version - 2.5.0
Node version -  8.0.0
OS - ubunut 16.04 LTS
Framework  - sailsJs

PM2 is not looking for any changes made in controller or policies or in models, I have to stop it again and then restart it.
Here is my process.json file

```
 {
    "apps" : [{
      "name"        : "vr_crs",
      "script"      : "app.js",
      "watch"     : true,
      "ignore_watch" : ["node_modules", "views"],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "env_local": {
        "NODE_ENV": "local"
      },
      "env_production" : {
         "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    }]
  }
```

and "pm2 start process.json --env local" that's how I am starting the pm2 local serve. any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt task `watch` in development mode doesn't watch changes in models, controllers or policies. For that you need to use [sails-hook-autoreload](https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload)

Ex:

```
// file - config/autoreload.js
module.exports.autoreload = {
  active: true,
  usePolling: false,
  dirs: [
    "api/models",
    "api/controllers",
    "api/services",
    "config/locales"
  ],
  ignored: [
    // Ignore all files with .ts extension
    "**.ts"
  ]
};
```